# Compiling & building CPP using LLVM (Clang) on Windows10

Tags: c++, windows, arm, clang, llvm

I installed LLVM on a clear Windows 10 machine, without anything else. I installed the ARMCompiler6.14.1. I have a simple cpp for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    printf("counter: %d", counter);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    printf("c++14 output");
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> vect{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (auto & el : vect)
        std::cout << "-" << el << std::endl;

    return counter;
}
```

When I compile this with following line I get errors:

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" -MD -x c++ "C:\Test\test.cpp" -target armv7a-none-eabi "-IC:\Program Files\ARMCompiler.6.14.1\include"
```

The error is:
test.cpp 2:10:fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

When I compile this with following line I get an windows executable which runs:

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" -MD -x c++ "C:\Test\test.cpp"
```

Since I checked that in the `LLVM\bin` is anything from the developer.arm.com package (ARMcompiler 6.14.1), I think that I should get an a.out for ARM, but I do not. When I checked the generated object file with:

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\llvm-objdump.exe" -f test.o
```

I get following:

```
test.o file format elf32-littlearm
arhitecture: arm
start adress: 0x00000000
```

which means the object file is correctly generated for ARM, but I did not get an executable a.out for ARM.

What am I missing? How should I compile a simple test program to get it cross-compiled for ARM? Should I get the binutil from GCC for the Clang to create ARM executables?

Comment: What you show is not an error, but the compile command. Please edit your question to show the errors. Are you crosscompiling of a RPi 3 or so?

Comment: I want to use clang cross compiling c and cpp on windows for ARM

Comment: all the rest of the items linked and how linked is specific to the target.  so you want to run a program in windows on arm?  and you are building on a non windows arm system?

Comment: when you build on the windows arm system natively does it work?

Comment: "fatal error: 'iostream' file not found" means that you do not even have the most important header files. How could you hope to compile anything at all without iostream?

Comment: why not `printf("counter: %d\n", counter);` instead of putting a separate `cout` just to print a new line?